# Data types in function call not matching up properly

Tags: c++, parameters

I have a function called generate_all_paths:

```
template <int size>
void generate_all_paths(vector<string> maze, int x, int y) {
....
}
```

When I call it in main:

```
int main() {
  vector<string> mazevec;
  string s;
  ifstream mazefile("maze.txt");

  while (getline(mazefile, s)) {
      mazevec.push_back(s);
  }

  generate_all_paths(mazevec, 0, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

My IDE says that my call to generate_all_paths in main does not match the data types of the parameters defined by the function.

Does anyone know why this is happening? What's throwing me off is that `mazevec` is defined as a vector, as is wanted by generate_all_paths, but it's not working.

Comment: Its a template function and you do not supply the template parameter nor can it be infered. ``generate_all_paths<42>(...)`` would look more like it.

Comment: A question for *you*, Why does your template function have a `size` template parameter *at all* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah I accidentally left that piece in there, but right now it should have no effect on why generate_all_paths does not have matching parameters, right? mazevec is a vector<string> and that's what the function asks for.

Comment: @cursayer it shouldn't?? did you at-least *try* to take it *off* the function decl?  Sure it isn't being used, but what makes you think it isn't required to be provided? I certainly isn't being deduced. Or perhaps try : `generate_all_paths<0>(mazevec, 0, 1);`, and when it works, consider why.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, I learned, that `template<int size>` was there by accident.
Thus, [I (and compiler)](http://goo.gl/w1aUzh) can't see any reason why your code should not compile.

Check that you have `#include <vector>` and `using namespace std;`, since you are not prefixing `vector` with `std::`.
Also it is good reason to pass `vector<string>` as `const &`.